# Non isomorphic groups who product with Z is isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

Are there groups $G$ and $H$ such that $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic but $G \times \mathbb Z$ and $H \times \mathbb Z$ are?

Comment: (Answer given in the answers to the question. Answers also link to similar questions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an example in a paper by Hirshon, "On Cancellation in Groups".  You can find a slightly different example written up [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=351637)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if one of them is abelian and finitely generated then by structure theorem $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

Comment: This is not correct. You need $G$ (and $H$) to be abelian for this to work.